# Remove duplicate from linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have written the code to remove duplicate from linked list, but I am not able to identify my mistake. Any possible suggestion or help would be appreciated.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

struct Node{
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node(int x){
    data=x;
    next=NULL;
  }
};

void fun(Node *head){
  Node *curr;
  //Node *temp=curr->next;
  //Node *prev;
  Node *ptr;
  for(curr=head;curr!=NULL;curr=curr->next){
    for(ptr=curr;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next){
      if(curr->data==ptr->data){
        Node *hold=ptr->next;   //to hold duplicate
        ptr->next=ptr->next->next;
        delete(hold);
      }
      //cout<<curr->data<<endl;
    }    
  }
}

void print(Node *head){
  Node *move=head;
  while(move!=NULL){
    cout<<move->data;
    move=move->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n,data1;
  cin>>n;
  cin>>data1;
  Node *head=new Node(data1);
  Node *temp=head;
  while(n-1!=0){
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    temp->next=new Node(x);
    temp=temp->next;
    n--;
  }
  
  fun(head);
  print(head);
}
```

Is there any mistake in the `fun` function or in calling the `fun` function? I think this is likely, but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: *I think most probably but I am not able to figure out.* -- However you wrote the code, so why is it not possible for you to debug the code that you wrote?  When you wrote the code, you must have had a plan written on paper beforehand -- so write the code so it follows your plan, or fix the code you wrote so that it does follow your plan correctly, or your plan was wrong and you need to start over.

Comment: When you delete, this advances forward. `ptr->next=ptr->next->next` then, the loop increment advances again, so you skip one element.

Comment: Also, I bet a simple linked list of 3 elements should have been tested, demonstrating the error, thus easier to debug to see what the issue is.

Comment: One important point that  PaulMcKenzie didn't explictly mention: *SINGLE STEP THROUGH YOUR CODE IN THE DEBUGGER*.  Learning to use the debugger is one of the most *IMPORTANT* skills you need to know.  If you're not already familiar with your compiler's debugger, and how to use it - now is a great time to learn!

Comment: *"I am not able to identify my mistake"* -- why do you believe there is a mistake? What are the symptoms? (This both helps future readers with the same issue find this question, and help current readers pinpoint which of your mistakes you are currently working on.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Node *hold=ptr->next;   //to hold duplicate
ptr->next=ptr->next->next;
delete(hold);
```

Here, you're holding the next ptr, which is not what the duplicate is. Node *hold = ptr is the duplicate, but since you don't have a prev ptr, you can't remove this duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main error is in your original `for` loop, where you do not traverse and process the nodes in the linked list correctly.

I have fixed your `for` loop, and it works now.

Also, I have removed your statement `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` with `#include <iostream>`. Instead, I have used `std::in` and `std::out`.

Here are the 2 reasons for not to include `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h%22)

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) in your program.

---

Here is my new code that works:

```
#include <iostream>

//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

struct Node{
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node(int x){
    data=x;
    next=NULL;
  }
};

void fun(Node *head){
  Node *curr;
  //Node *temp=curr->next;
  //Node *prev;
  Node *ptr;
  for(curr=head;curr!=NULL;curr=curr->next){
      
      if (curr->next == NULL)
         return;
      
    for(ptr=curr->next;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next){
      if(curr->data==ptr->data){
        Node *hold=ptr;   //to hold duplicate
        curr->next=ptr->next;
        delete(hold);
      }
      else
          break;
      
      //cout<<curr->data<<endl;
    }    
  }
}

void print(Node *head){
  Node *move=head;
  while(move!=NULL){
    std::cout<<move->data;
    move=move->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n,data1;
  std::cin>>n;
  std::cin>>data1;
  Node *head=new Node(data1);
  Node *temp=head;
  while(n-1!=0){
    int x;
    std::cin>>x;
    temp->next=new Node(x);
    temp=temp->next;
    n--;
  }
  
  fun(head);
  print(head);
}
```

---

If you run into any other issue during testing, please let me know. But, the code above works for my test cases.

Comment: Thanks for help, but for sample input-1 8 3 5 7 9 10 15 9 it is giving a wrong output-1 8 3 5 7 9 10 15 9 ,but the correct output is 1 8 3 5 7 9 10 15. I will also try to figure it out. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Segmentationfault, Oh.  I did not know that your linked list is unsorted. Can you check to see if your assignment actually states that the linked list is unsorted ? If yes, then another solution would be faster :  using an ```unordered_map```.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you delete the wrong node. condition in if could be something like :

```
if(curr->data==ptr->next->data) {
    //delete ptr->next，
}
```

Ofcause, ptr->next should be checked before if.